# difference between running and publish a paginated report

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, reportbuilder

I recently started going through resource material on microsoft about paginated report. Could anybody help me understand the difference between a Paginated Report Definition -- Running the Report -- Publish the report (to power BI service).

I have attached the link for the source for the information where I encountered the above mentioned concern, and it is under the heading: **Creating a Report definition**

the title of the page: **what are the paginated reports in Power BI Premium?**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/paginated-reports/paginated-reports-report-builder-power-bi

Thank you for giving your valuable time!

Comment: Paginating reports in Power BI are actually SQL server reporting services reports.  Anything(almost) you read about SQL server reporting services can be applied to Power BI paginated reports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The report definition is the 'rdl' file. This is an xml based file that includes all the items for the connections, the visuals and anything else in the report. This is the file you build in the designer.

When you the publish the report, you'll loading that definition to the service, like you do with standard Power BI reports. When you use that report in the service or designer you are running it, in which case it will use the connections/queries in the report to run a query on your data source, collect the results, then display the data.

Unlike standard Power BI reports, there is no importing of the data to the report to a dataset, in which you can interact with. As a result of that if you need to change anything in the report, for example change a filter, it will run those queries again on your data, which is why it is limited in data sources options to those items with some sort of compute capacity, SQL Database etc, rather than a flat file source.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, John

Comment: No problem, if you think the answer helps please click accept

Comment: couldn't find accept button to accept the solution!

Comment: There should be a tick icon on the answer, click that to accept